# How to play 1080p video on Bravia Full HD from sony 768p vaio

Tags: hdmi, 1080p

I am trying to watch 1080p movies from 768p laptop using HDMI cable, which is not mirroring as 1080p. Could some one help on this situation?

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: What OS do you use ?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976064